# get label from notebook tab

Tags: pygtk

I have a gtk.Notebook and i want get text of label from current gtk.noteBook tab.
I make that:

```
text = self.get_tab_label(self.get_nth_page(self.get_current_page()))
```

if i `print text` i see:

But in gtk help i read that: get_tab_label_text: returnvalue: the text of the tab label, or None if the tab label widget is not a gtk.Label.

How can i get tet from label in this situation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any gtk.Widget can be a Notebook tab label. It is usually a gtk.Label, but not always. So two API methods exist to cover both situations:

1. [gtk.Notebook.get_tab_label()](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtknotebook.html#method-gtknotebook--get-tab-label) returns a gtk.Widget that is the label widget. If it is a gtk.Label, you will need to call [gtk.Label.get_text()](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtklabel.html#method-gtklabel--get-text) to get the text.
2. [gtk.Notebook.get_tab_label_text()](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtknotebook.html#method-gtknotebook--set-tab-label-text) returns a string of text ***only if*** the label widget is a gtk.Label, otherwise will return None.